# printing something in a row a certain amount of times

Tags: python, twitch

I'm making a twitch bot and would like to have a pyramid command that will send a sideways pyramid in chat that looks like this =>  https://i.stack.imgur.com/oW0ws.png

currently its printing it all in one line however its printing the right amount but its supposed to be sideways not upright.

changing the pyramid_width to "a" fixes it however it needs to send the word specified in chat. https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zptc1.png

I'm not sure on how I can actually fix this so any help would be appreciated <3

```
  def send_pyramid(width, text, channel):
        text = str(text) + " " if not str(text).endswith(" ") else str(text)
        while text.find('  ') != -1:
            text.replace('  ', ' ')
        for i in range(0, width + 1):
            sendcommand("/me " + i * text, channel)
        width -= 1
        while width != 0:
            sendcommand("/me " + width * text, channel)
            width -= 1


    def get_first_nbr_from_str(input_str):
        '''
        :param input_str: strings that contains digit and words
        :return: the number extracted from the input_str
        demo:
        'ab324.23.123xyz': 324.23
        '.5abc44': 0.5
        '''
        if not input_str and not isinstance(input_str, str):
            return 0
        out_number = ''
        for ele in input_str:
            if (ele == '.' and '.' not in out_number) or ele.isdigit():
                out_number += ele
            elif out_number:
                break
        return float(out_number)


    def clearup(s, chars):
        return re.sub('[%s]' % chars, '', s).lower()

    if "++test" in chat:
        echo = chat.replace("++test","")
        echo = str(echo)
        pyramid_width = (get_first_nbr_from_str(echo)) # finds the number
        pyramid_width = int(pyramid_width)
        pyramid_text = clearup(echo, string.punctuation+string.digits) # replaces number
        print(pyramid_text)
        for i in range(0, pyramid_width + 1):
            print(i * pyramid_text)
        pyramid_width -= 1
        while pyramid_width != 0:
            print(pyramid_width * pyramid_text)
            pyramid_width -= 1
```

Comment: did you try to add `'\n'`  at the end

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/arIel4I.png where exactly would I put it?

Comment: when you use `print()` then it automatically use `\n` at the end - so you don't need it in `print()`. I was thinking  about `sendcommand("/me " + i * text + '\n', channel)`. But I don't use `twitch` to test it.

Comment: It doesnt seem to work right, its just one long line of text instead of a pyramid, if i replace the  pyramid text to just  a letter it works fine  but idk

Comment: you should send  every line in separated `sendcommand()`

Comment: frankly I don't see where you send `pyramid_text` with `sendcommand()` - if you send all text in one `sendcommand()` then it may send it as one long string. You should send every line in separated `sendcommand()`